# Flutter improves ExpansionTile with ListView.builder performance

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, listview, expansion-tile

I am trying to do create a view of `ExpansionTile` with `ListView.builder` as children. It works well but just if my `ListView.builder` become larger, it will need to take some time to render it which slightly affect the user expereince. Is there anyway to help to improve the performance for this?

Below is my sample code:

```
ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(title),
  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
  initiallyExpanded: true,
  maintainState: true,  
  children: [
     ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => widgetList[index],
        )
  ])
```

Comment: Get rid of shrinkWrap: true.  You defeat the entire point of the builder by first requiring that the sizes of all items be computed first.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz i get error after i get rid of the shrinkWrap...

Answer (score 1):

**1. shrinkWrap**

I would suggest to get rid of shirnkWrap (if possible), as it calculates the size of all elements in the list.

**2. ItemBuilder**

Also, I recommend to be aware of the operations inside the itemBuilder, because it can slow down rendering the items.

Comment: i get an error if i change the shrinkWrap to false...